# Custom iterator and proxy pattern C++

Tags: c++, iterator

The task was: Create a custom iterator to work with files.

I also was told to use a proxy pattern which is new to me. Is there everything I can change to make my code look better?

Or maybe I have some slight errors which my compiler fixed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class IntFile
{
public:
    int value;
    FILE* file;


    IntFile()
    {
        file = fopen("text.txt", "r+b");
    }

    ~IntFile()
    {

        fclose(file);
    }
    virtual int& getValue(int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&value, 4, 1, file);
        return value;
    }

    virtual int setValue(int value, int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&value, 4, sizeof(value),file);
        return 0;
    }


    class Proxy
    {
    private:
        IntFile *ptr;
        long index;
    public:
        Proxy(IntFile* ptr3, int idx)
        {
            ptr = ptr3;
            index = idx;
        }
        Proxy& operator=(int value)
        {
            ptr->setValue(value, index);
        }
        operator int() const
        {
            return ptr->getValue(index);
            cout << "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" << endl;
        }

    };

    friend struct iterator;
    struct iterator
    {
        int index;
        int value2;
        IntFile* ptr;

        iterator(IntFile* ptr2, int idx, FILE* ptrfile)
        {
            ptr = ptr2;
            index = idx;
            fseek(ptrfile, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        }

        iterator (int i = 0) : value2(i)
        {

        }

        bool operator==(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index == other.index;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index!=other.index;
        }
        Proxy operator*()
        {
            return Proxy(ptr, index);
        }
        int &operator=(int value)
        {
            this->value2 = value;
        }
        iterator &operator=(const iterator& other)
        {
            this->value2 = other.value2;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator&operator++()
        {
            this->index = index+1;
        }
        iterator&operator--()
        {
            this->index = index -1;
        }
        iterator operator+=(int index2)
        {
            this->index = index + index2;
        }
        iterator operator+(const iterator& other)
        {
            return iterator(value2 + other.value2);
        }
        iterator operator-(const iterator& other)
        {
            return iterator(value2 - other.value2);
        }

    };
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(this, 0, file);
    }
    iterator end(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number, file);
    }
    iterator rbegin(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number-1, file);
    }
    iterator rend()
    {
        return iterator(this, -1, file);
    }
};


int main()
{
    IntFile myfile;

    int number;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    vector <int> myVector;

    cout << "Enter your numbers: ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cin >> myfile.value;
        myVector.push_back(myfile.value);
    }

    fwrite(&myVector[0], sizeof(vector<int>::value_type), myVector.size(),myfile.file);

    cout << endl << "FORWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.begin(); i != myfile.end(number); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }


    cout << endl << "BACKWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.rbegin(number); i != myfile.rend(); --i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }


    IntFile::iterator i = myfile.begin();

    /** *i = value **/
    int a = 75;
    *i = a;
    cout << endl << endl << "75 should be here: " << *i << endl;

    /** int value = *i **/
    int k = 0;
    k = *i;
    cout << "76 should be here: " << k+1 << endl;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see my input and output just in case.

```
Input: 
10, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Output:
FORWARD 1 by 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
BACKWARD 1 by 1: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
75 should be here: 75
76 should be here: 76
```

Comment: You know there is an iterator that works with streams (ie files) as part of the standard. `std::istream_iterator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Implementation

- `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice and should be avoided.
- Naming: Many variable names tell nothing about their meaning. For example, what does `value2` do? How is it different from `value`? Better names enhance the readability of the code!
- The `IntFile` constructor should probably take the path to the file as a parameter (there might be other files than "test.txt").
- The `IntFile` constructor never initializes `IntFile::value`.
- `IntFile::file` and `IntFile::value` should probably be private.
- `file` is never checked if it actually is a valid file handle.
- Rule of 3/5 violation: `IntFile` acquires a resource and has a custom destructor. As such, the copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator should also be manually implemented or deleted (the compiler generated ones will very likely do the wrong thing).
- `getValue` and `setValue` assume that `sizeof(int)` will always be 4 bytes. This is not the case! (e.g. if compiled for 64bit, `sizeof(int) == 8`)
- `getValue` and `setValue` aren't aware of endianess. This can mean that writing a value `0x00000001` on one platform will be read as `0x01000000` on another.
- `setValue`s return value is always the same. Maybe its return type should be changed to `void`?
- `friend struct iterator` does not refer to `IntFile::iterator`, but to `std::iterator` instead (reason: no forward declaration for `IntFile::iterator` and `using namespace std;` combined with `#include <vector>`).
- `iterator::iterator(IntFile*, int, int)` never initializes `iterator::value2`.
- `iterator::iterator(IntFile*, int, int)` unnecessarily calls `fseek`.
- `iterator::iterator(int)` does not initialize `iterator::ptr` and `iterator::index`, thus setting every subsequent operation up for undefined behavior (e.g. dereferncing `iterator::ptr`).
- `iterator &iterator::operator=(const iterator&)` never assigns `iterator::ptr` and `iterator::index`.
- `int &iterator::operator=(int)` never returns an `int` value.
- `iterator &iterator::operator++()` never returns a `iterator&`.
- `iterator &iterator::operator--()` never returns a `iterator&`.
- `iterator &iterator::operator+=(int)` never returns a `iterator&`.
- I can't imagine what `iterator::operator+(const iterator&)` or `iterator::operator-(const iterator&)` would be used for.
- `IntFile::end(int)` never checks if `Number` is out of bounds (could be negative or too large).
- `IntFile::rbegin()` and `IntFile::rend(int)` should probably return `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>` instead (currently iterating backwards has to be done with `--iter` instead of the expected `++iter`.
- `Proxy::index` should be of the same type as the parameter `index` of `IntFile::setValue` and `IntFile::getValue` to prevent slicing errors (`sizeof(long)` might be greater than `sizeof(int)`).
- The call to print to `std::cout` in `Proxy::operator int()` is never reached.

## Design

- `IntFile::setValue`: I'd expect the first parameter to be the index and the second parameter to be the value).
- `IntFile` could provide an overload for `operator[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience! I appreciate it! I've changed as much as I could